# sherlock SearchView always collapsed

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i want to see a searchView with Sherlock library. this is my activity:

```
public class PointActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
.
.
.

@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.point, menu);
  return true;
}
```

this is my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

why my searchview is always collapsed? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand the `SearchView` on activity start, add these lines to `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
searchItem.expandActionView();
```

Comment: Did you put it in the right place? I just tested it on Android 4.2 and Android 2.2. It works as expected.